# can't get json array in android

Tags: android, json, arrays

I'm trying to get json data from a php script into my android application but the `getJSONFromUrl(URL);` doesn't work. Below is my code..

MAINACTIVITY CLASS

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:1234/main.php/";
private JSONArray words = null;
private ArrayList<String> wordsList;
private static final String TAG_WORDS = "words";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    wordsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    updateJSONdata();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), wordsList.toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void updateJSONdata() {      
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL);// this is where the error is
    try {
        words = json.getJSONArray(TAG_WORDS);
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = words.getJSONObject(i);
            String title = c.toString();
            wordsList.add(title);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

JSONParser Class

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = ""; 
public JSONParser() {
}    

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(final String url) {
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }       
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }       
    return jObj;
}   
}
```

JSON data from main.php

```
{"words":[["bra"],["fie"]],"success":1}
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
$username = "root"; 
$password = ""; 
$host = "localhost"; 
$dbname = "dictionary_db"; 
$con=mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
if(!$con) die('could not connect'. mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname,$con);
$query = "SELECT word from local_words" ;
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$count = 0;
$wordsArr = array();
$response["words"] = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
    array_push($wordsArr,$row);
    $count++;
}
$response["success"] = 1;   
$response["words"] = $wordsArr;
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Error message in LogCat:

```
Buffer Error : Error converting result.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
JSON Parser : Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

Comment: ''' "words":[word1,word2] ''' is enum items. You should use getNames method.

Comment: Updated my answer with solution path, check it out

Answer (score 1):

`{"success":1,"words":[word1,word2]}` is not a valid JSON. A valid JSON should look like this

`{"success":1,"words":["word1","word2"]}`

Check your server response if the JSON is being sent correctly. It would help if you add more info what and how exactly your server returns the JSON.

**UPDATE**

You have two errors -

1. `Buffer Error - lock == null`. Reason - You are passing a `null` value to `InputStreamReader`, i.e. **`httpEntity.getContent();`** is null.
2. `JSON Error` - the parser is trying to parse an empty string, i.e at character 0

Either the `HTTP POST` method is not supported or there is some other error from server. You need to check the status of `httpResponse` and log that too. That will nail down the problem

**Another Update**

You are getting Socket Exception - Permission Denied, the problem here is you haven't added the Internet permission to the app. Go to your manifest, and add the below permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Try it and let me know if it helps.

Comment: Please update it on your question post along with printing how it appears on a browser if the url is called directly in the address bar

Comment: Please i'm having issues logging the `httpResponse` status.
Can you please help me out? I'm a bit novice in android.

Comment: Try logging the status using `httpRespons.getStatusLine()` and update

Comment: output of:

    `Log.d("httpresponse", "Status code is "+ httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());`

is:

    `java.net.SocketException: Permission denied`

Comment: Looks like you are missing the internet permission in your manifest. Updated my answer with it, check it out